# How can I find the binary dependency of msnodesql

Tags: node.js, odbc, backend, mssql-jdbc, msnodesqlv8

I have ELF header error because binary dependencies not match the architecture of node module.

I am building nodejs server on docker with manual transfer node_modules and install all dependencies required to connect with odbc sql.

I have succeed build but when I run I got the error with ELF headsr msnodesqlv8

To solve I can simply just npm install or rebuild.  But do you guys have any idea to solve this problem without npm install or npm rebuild?

Do you know where can I download this binary dependency of msnodesqlv8 for linux/amd64.

Thanks

Anything help find the the resource or fixing bug

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.